# Connect to secure websites inside html frame/iframe

Tags: html, iframe, frame

I am trying to set up a dashboard for my IT group to view several different servers in one web page.

I have 4 frames set up, and tested them with cnn or apple.com to make sure everything was set up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<frameset cols="40%,60%" rows="50%,50%">
<frame src="http://www.apple.com">
<frame src="http://www.cnn.com">
<frame src="http://www.espn.com">
<frame src="http://10.2.0.252/">
</frameset>

</html>
```

So, when loading `"http://10.2.0.252"`, it redirects to the login page `(https://10.2.0.252)` but opens the full page and does not keep it within the frame. The only thing on the page now is the login. The actual link for this is "https://" but when I put this in the code, the page is blank.

Is it possible to get the authentication page to stay inside the frame? I want to create frames that can be interactive so we can log in to the servers to view all of the status'.

EDIT: I am trying to display the https link in an iframe, but it just displays a blank screen. Does anyone know why `<iframe src="https://10.2.0.252" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>` will not at least bring up the login? It does not showing anything at the moment.

Comment: If all you need is a status (like the server is up), could you use a web service or a script to verify you get an HTTP OK status message as a reply? That would get around using the frames - nothing will stop your users from interacting with the frames, and strange things can happen if they do...

Comment: I need to log in to the Sonicwall and Aruba and other services that will give me specific information. I just want the redirect for the secure page to stay in the frame/iframe.

Comment: Some sites are configured to not be framed. I don't know if you can force it (I've never tried). You may need to have the user begin with the unframed site, log in and check the "Remember me" option if there is one, and then visit your frames.

Comment: I was also thinking about doing something like that, but am not sure how to go about that. If I load the page and log in, how do I then visit the frames?

Comment: If the site uses a "Remember me" function, I think they usually plant a cookie that keeps you logged in. When you go back in the frames (using a bookmark or typing the URL in the address bar), that cookie is still on your machine (long as you don't clear it), and it should let you back in without needing to enter a password. Not every site offers this feature, but many do.

Comment: It seems like this https site I am trying to load in the iFrame, has a FrameKiller. If it sees the site is trying to load in a frame, it kicks out a loads in the top page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to rethink your system.

If the site has a framekiller on it, you're wasting time trying to override it. There may be an API you can use - check with the sites to see if they offer one.